# How would I loop through an object to remove all numbers greater than 100?

Tags: javascript, object

I get that I need to use a for in loop, I'm just not sure what I need to put in to remove the properties greater than 100.

Here is the object:

```
var deleteTheBigNumbers = {
  first: 10,
  second: 20,
  third: 110,
  fourth: 200
}
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Testing if a number if more than 100, or removing a property?

Comment: you want [the `delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key,index) {
    if(obj[key] > 100){
//Do stuff
}
});

Comment: @TylerDahle That is good but I think it should be `if(obj[key] ....)`.

Comment: Oh right haha. Fixed it

Comment: Also, Object.keys(obj) method has the benefit of only looking at properties that would be true with obj.hasOwnProperty(someProperty). With the 'var key in someObj' way, you can end up iterating through object prototype properties, which could trip you up depending on what you are doing.

Comment: I actually figured it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous ways to handle this. This is one possible way:

```js
var deleteTheBigNumbers = {
  first: 10,
  second: 20,
  third: 110,
  fourth: 200
}

for (var key in deleteTheBigNumbers) {
  if (deleteTheBigNumbers[key] >= 100) {
    delete deleteTheBigNumbers[key];
  }
}

console.log(deleteTheBigNumbers);
```

Lodash also has a [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#pickBy) function which can do this as well:

```js
var deleteTheBigNumbers = {
  first: 10,
  second: 20,
  third: 110,
  fourth: 200
}

console.log(_.pickBy(deleteTheBigNumbers, (num) => num <= 100));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  for (let key in obj) {
         if (obj[key] >= 100) {
              delete obj[key];
          }
   }
```

Comment: for in loops can be sketchy in JavaScript.

Comment: @Espen: It doesn't really matter here because `delete` will only work on "own" properties. The `for-in` isn't the problem. The problem is usually developers loading 3rd party code without knowing what nasty things it does.

Comment: @rockstar the problem isn't just the prototype properties, but also if this object had methods and other properties that have different types. For instance, if this object had a method, if the logic was the "not equal" operator instead of the "greater than or equal", the method would have been deleted as well. Not necessarily what you expect. I am not saying that the solution isn't correct, but it is only correct in this highly special case. And not necessarily in general.

Comment: @Espen: Sure, but not all solutions need to be generalized, and Paul's answer doesn't attempt to generalize it by making a function. There's sometimes a notion that all code needs to fit a myriad of possibilities when often it makes more sense to write specific code for a specific situation.

Comment: I do agree that not all code needs to be generalized. But in this case, it is only usable on objects with no other properties than numerical. My argument is that one should aim at least to produce safe code. Which is why I warn against using the for in loop. Not saying you shouldn't do it, but saying proceed with caution.

Comment: @Espen: The `for-in` isn't unsafe. What's unsafe is allowing coding practices that make it unsafe.  Adding enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` has a far greater potential for causing problems, because now all other code needs to anticipate and adjust to that code. However, even doing that is safe as long as you guarantee that *all* other code doesn't conflict with that practice.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a more generic filtering function.

```js
var deleteTheBigNumbers = {
    first: 10,
    second: 20,
    third: 110,
    fourth: 200
};


Object.prototype.oFilter = function (f) {
    var newobj = {};
    var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
        if (f(this[keys[i]])) {
            newobj[keys[i]] = this[keys[i]];
        }
    }
    return newobj;
};
var filtered = deleteTheBigNumbers.oFilter(function (v) {
    return v <= 100;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```